# Numerical Integration with Trapezoidal rule c++

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

I'm attempting to implement a Trapezoidal rule that utilizes previous function evaluations in order to avoid redundant computation. Two things: a) computed results are not converging and I'm a little unsure of why. I'll post of the mathematics behind why I think that the algorithm should yield convergence if it's wanted, and b) the do while loop is terminating at n=8 and I've been unable to figure that one out as well; it should be running until n>128? (n is the number of subintervals) My code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
void NestedTrap(int n) //Trapezoidal with reuse of function evaluations
{
    double a,b; //interval end points
    double x[n+1]; //equally spaced nodes
    double c[n]; //midpoints
    double T; //Initial integral evaluation
    double T2; //Evaluation with reuse of previous function evaluations
    double h, h2; //step sizes for T and T2
    double temp1, temp2;

    std::cout <<"Enter interval end points (lesser first; enter 999 for pi & 999.2 for pi/2 & 999.4 for pi/4): ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    if (b == 999)
    {
        b = M_PI;
    }
    if (a == 999)
    {
        a = M_PI;
    }
    if (b == 999.4)
    {
        b = M_PI/4;
    }
    if (a == 999.4)
    {
        a = M_PI/4;
    }
    if (b == 999.2)
    {
        b = M_PI/2;
    }
    if (a == 999.2)
    {
        a = M_PI/2;
    }

    h = (b-a)/n;
    T = 0;
    temp1 = 0;
    temp2 = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        temp1 += I1(x[i]);
    }
    T = (h/2)*exp(x[0]) + (h/2)*exp(x[n]) + (h*temp1);
    std::cout << "T_" << n <<": " << T << std::endl;

    do
    {
    temp2 = 0;
    n = 2*n;
    h2 = (b-a)/(n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        c[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        c[i] = a + h2*(i-0.5);
        //std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        temp2 += exp(c[i]);
    }

    T2 = (T/2) + h2*temp2;
    std::cout << "T_" << n <<": " << T2 << std::endl;

    T = T2;
    }   while (n <= 128);
}
```

Comment: Also I've been running the closed interval [0,3]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything you are doing here. Why are you messing with **e**? Isn't `I1()` the function you are integrating over? Also, you are using VLAs, which isn't a good idea, nor even necessary. For **n** intervals, you need pull (n+1) points of data from your function, applying the trapezoidal rule to every pair: the one you just pulled and the last one you pulled, summing them. If `I1()` is continuous, it will converge automagically.

Comment: Also, in the loop you are doubling up n, and accessing x[i] and c[i] while c[] and x[] have been previously sized for the initial value of n. You will fall out of bounds of these arrays...

Comment: btw my VS2015 compiler refuses to compile x[n+1] and c[n]. This is not standard C++.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I meant to change all the I1() to exp() so that you would know what function I was integrating with respect to. It wasn't necessary, but I thought it might be helpful for contextual purposes. So if I assign the value of n to another variable and implement that variable throughout the remainder of the code will that eliminate the VLA issue? Right I expect it to converge. I'm attempting to first evaluate n intervals. Upon doing that I want to double the amount of intervals. Then I want to use the already computed n intervals and merely add, to that value, function values at new nodes

Comment: Ideally that should keep me from having to recompute already evaluated intervals, and I can minimize the amount of computation needed to reach a suitable evaluation that lies within desired error bounds. Did that make sense?

Comment: @A.S.H sorry I should have tagged c instead. It runs fine for me in Eclipse. As for moving outside the bounds of my array you're spot on. Thank you, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create arrays of size `n` here

```
double x[n+1]; //equally spaced nodes
double c[n]; //midpoints
```

(note that this is not valid c++)

then you increase `n` here:

```
n = 2*n;
```

then you write past the end of your array here:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    c[i] = 0;
}
```

which causes undefined behaviour (probably overwrites some other variables)

Comment: Nice catch! I totally missed that.